# C#: Rendering too many controls in one form, but in different tabs

Tags: c#, rendering, tabcontrol

I just started making a wizard application. I have used a header-less tabcontrol to build different pages of that wizard.

I have read that having too many controls can slow the rendering process specially in form resizing. For example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724202/c-sharp-winforms-efficiently-displaying-many-controls) 225 button slows the rendering. I have many controls (hundreds of them) but they are not all shown because they are distributed in different tab and only one tab is shown which only contains like 20 controls.

I am afraid that after finishing my application, it will be a slow piece of garbage. Is C# smart enough to render only shown controls? or should I choose a different approach to create my wizard?

Comment: I wrote something similar 12 years ago and had to create a process to load the controls when the Tab got focus. Since this is really asking for an opinion I would look for another solution or third party controls.

Comment: @RyanPeters :( I think I must search for another way then. thank you. you saved me from programming for months only to get embarrassed and probably fired!!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that C# is smart!

If i create hundreds of controls but in different tab, my application drawing wont be that slow. but if i add them all in one tab(they are rendered in the same time) drawing(and resizing and moving) of from will be slow.

(I wrote my application and it works fine)